# Preposition for an Item on a list

Tags: prepositions

I wrote:

> After the page has loaded, you can apply a filter **from** the **Filters** box to automatically extract the main content and eliminate clutter.

The Filters box is:

[image]

Did I use **from** correctly?

However I could also say it as:

> After the page has loaded, you can **select** a filter **from** the **Filters** box and apply it to automatically extract the main content and eliminate clutter.

But I feel it is verbose.

Comment: Proper *from* use; stick with *apply*.

Comment: If you say "extract *only* the main content" you could eliminate clutter by eliminating **and eliminate clutter**.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of "from" and "apply" are correct.  However, I would use words like "select" and "choose," since the button is named "apply," just to avoid any confusion.   This is an example of what I would write:

> To eliminate clutter on the page, choose a filter from the **Filters** box, and then select *Apply.*

This also makes the sentence less verbose.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of **from** is correct.

If you use the following wording

> After the page has loaded, you can **select** a filter from the Filters box and click **Apply** to automatically extract the main content**s** and eliminate (any) clutter.

It will keep your steps in sequential order and ties in the **Apply** (note capitalisation to reflect the label on the button) click button.

Answer (score 0):

The main point of this process is to eliminate clutter, so I would start with that. Also, it's best to keep infinitives intact.

Yours:

> After the page has loaded, you can apply a filter from the Filters box to automatically extract the main content and eliminate clutter.

Suggestion:

> To eliminate clutter, you can extract the main content automatically by applying a filter from the Filters box after the page has loaded.

Comment: As it is a step of a instruction I described it in sequence.